# How to change Storyboard animation from sliding up to down?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a program that slides up a page in which you can enter info into and when use my swipe gesture to go back it slides up. Is there a way to change the animation from sliding up to down?

Comment: The answer is, probably, yes. But in order to provide more details, you will need to provide more details, such as some code and more info about how that "storyboard animation" is invoked.

Comment: I set up a button that will change the page with a modal segue, and a swipe down gesture on that page that will go back to the first page with a modal segue. Thats really all the information I can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using another modal segue to go back to the first page, use an IBAction along with [dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_51)

First, delete your modal segue that goes back to the first page.

Then, in your second page (UIViewController) where you have implemented the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, create the following in your .h and .m files:

```
//secondPage.h

- (IBAction)dismissViewControllerOnSwipe;
```

---

```
//secondPage.m
 - (IBAction)dismissViewControllerOnSwipe
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

Finally, go to your UISwipeGestureRecognizer in your storyboard and navigate to the connections inspector. Add the `dismissViewControllerOnSwipe` method under "Sent Actions" as shown below:

[image: Sent Actions]

This should make the animation slide down back to the "first page" after swiping downward.